# Vaadin TestBench: Access input field in Vaadin grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-testbench

A Vaadin grid contains an input field. How to enter into this input field with Vaadin Testbench 23.1.15? The GridTHTDElement Java class does not provide any methods for this.

Comment: You need to give more details to this question. Is the input field Vaadin TextField? How it has been added to Grid's cell? Using Component Renderer or is it used via Grid's Editor? Does the input field have id attribute set or other things that can help to determine specific field from the others?

Comment: Does the HTML help?:
<vaadin-grid-cell-content slot="vaadin-grid-cell-content-15">
<flow-component-renderer appid="ROOT" nodeid="417">
<vaadin-text-field has-value="" style="width: 100%;">
<input slot="input" value="0" type="text" id="vaadin-text-field-5" pattern="^[-,+]?([0-9][.,]?)*$" focus-target="true">
<label slot="label" id="label-vaadin-text-field-5" for="vaadin-text-field-5"></label>
<div slot="error-message" id="error-message-vaadin-text-field-5" hidden=""></div>
I'm not the GUI developer. I'm the tester.

Comment: The TextField is slotted, which means it is not in Shadow DOM, you should be able to find it using the id "vaadin-text-field-5".

Comment: Using ID "vaadin-text-field-5" doesn't seems to be stable...

Comment: You can give dedicated id by using textField.setId("my-text-field") that will be stable. Note, it needs to be unique.